# Mask by n bytes

Tags: c, byte, mask, masking, bitmask

I struggle masking a uint64_t variable by N bytes. I do not know N but I know it is 8 or less. My current code looks like this:

```
// uint64_t n is given
uint64_t mask;
for( mask = 0x00; n; n--) {
    mask = mask<<8 | 0xFF;
}
```

for building the mask. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
The question was answered. Anyway, for better understanding:

I want a mask like this:

```
0x000000FF // or:
0x0000FFFF // or:
0x00FFFFFF
```

to take 1, 2 or more byte from the data. As the comments say, my code works! Maybe I had an bug anywere else!

Comment: Works fine for me.  Is this the real code.  Explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: An example of input data and expected output data would also help us to provide a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, according to the [operator precendence table1].

Still, it's more clear to write it as:

```
mask <<= 8;
mask |= 0xff;
```

or:

```
mask = (mask << 8) | 0xff;
```

You can also do it with a look-up table, of course.

Comment: No he's not - << takes precedence over |. (you did read that link yourself?).  It would only fail if he used + instead of |

Comment: Actually I retract the -1 because adding the brackets is still better coding style.

Comment: @Pete Thanks, I was actually a bit uncertain but didn't take the time to test. I tried to express that, but not very clearly. Rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get the question right, but your mask looks like

```
0x00000000000000ff
0x000000000000ffff
0x0000000000ffffff
...
```

I assume that you want something like the following, to mask individual bytes:

```
0x00000000000000ff
0x000000000000ff00
0x0000000000ff0000
...
```

For this, you can use e.g. the following code:

```
for( mask = 0xff; n; n--) {

    // Use the mask HERE
    ...

    mask = mask<<8;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's my fault. My question was badly worded, I wanted the first one. Anyway, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code snippet, to replace the `byteno`th byte with `dest` mask, in `src`:

```
uint64_t replacemyByte(uint64_t src, uint64_t byteno,uint64_t dest) 
{
    uint64_t shift = (dest << (8 * byteno));
    uint64_t mask = 0xff << shift;
    return (~mask & src) | shift;
}
```

Or did I get the question wrong?